# Milo: Connect to (public) OPC-UA-Server

Tags: eclipse, opc-ua, milo

First of all: I'm a newbie to OPCUA. :)

I'm trying to connect an Milo Client to our Server but don't really understand whats going wrong. The sample Client and Server work fine together, but when I try to connect the client sample with one of the public OPC-UA-Test-Servers I get those exceptions:

> 15:48:34.729 [ua-netty-event-loop-0] DEBUG
>   org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.client.handlers.UaTcpClientAcknowledgeHandler
>   - Sent Hello message on channel=[id: 0xc22800c2, L:/10.22.19.217:58947 - R:opcua.demo-this.com/52.233.134.134:51210]. 15:48:34.729 [ua-netty-event-loop-0] WARN io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline -
>   An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of
>   the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did
>   not handle the exception. java.io.IOException: An existing connection
>   was forcibly closed by the remote host    at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)    at
>   sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)     at
>   io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:221)
>     at
>   io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:898)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:242)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:485)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:399)
>     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:371)     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 15:48:39.612
>   [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] DEBUG
>   org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.client.ClientChannelManager - Channel
>   bootstrap failed: timed out waiting for acknowledge
>   org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.UaException: timed out waiting for
>   acknowledge   at
>   org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.client.handlers.UaTcpClientAcknowledgeHandler.lambda$startHelloTimeout$4(UaTcpClientAcknowledgeHandler.java:156)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.client.handlers.UaTcpClientAcknowledgeHandler$$Lambda$27/469017260.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:581)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelBucket.expireTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:655)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:367)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 15:48:39.613 [main] ERROR
>   org.eclipse.milo.examples.client.ClientExampleRunner - Error running
>   example: UaException: status=Bad_Timeout, message=timed out waiting
>   for acknowledge java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: UaException:
>   status=Bad_Timeout, message=timed out waiting for acknowledge     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1887)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.milo.examples.client.ClientExampleRunner.createClient(ClientExampleRunner.java:56)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.milo.examples.client.ClientExampleRunner.run(ClientExampleRunner.java:103)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.milo.examples.client.BrowseExample.main(BrowseExample.java:40)
>   Caused by: org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.UaException: timed out
>   waiting for acknowledge   at
>   org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.client.handlers.UaTcpClientAcknowledgeHandler.lambda$startHelloTimeout$4(UaTcpClientAcknowledgeHandler.java:156)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.client.handlers.UaTcpClientAcknowledgeHandler$$Lambda$27/469017260.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:581)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelBucket.expireTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:655)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:367)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 15:48:42.842
>   [threadDeathWatcher-2-1] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache - Freed
>   2 thread-local buffer(s) from thread: ua-netty-event-loop-0

I took the sample-Code and removed the Certificate/Keypair and changed the URL to `opc.tcp://opcua.demo-this.com:51210/UA/SampleServer` since the public server doesn't need authorization:

```
SecurityPolicy securityPolicy = clientExample.getSecurityPolicy();
EndpointDescription[] endpoints = UaTcpStackClient.getEndpoints("opc.tcp://opcua.demo-this.com:51210/UA/SampleServer").get();

EndpointDescription endpoint = Arrays.stream(endpoints)
    .filter(e -> e.getSecurityPolicyUri().equals(securityPolicy.getSecurityPolicyUri()))
    .findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("no desired endpoints returned"));

logger.info("Using endpoint: {} [{}]", endpoint.getEndpointUrl(), securityPolicy);

loader.load();

OpcUaClientConfig config = OpcUaClientConfig.builder()
    .setApplicationName(LocalizedText.english("eclipse milo opc-ua client"))
    .setApplicationUri("urn:eclipse:milo:examples:client")
    //.setCertificate(loader.getClientCertificate())
    //.setKeyPair(loader.getClientKeyPair())
    .setEndpoint(endpoint)
    .setIdentityProvider(clientExample.getIdentityProvider())
    .setRequestTimeout(uint(5000))
    .build();

return new OpcUaClient(config);
```

What am I missing?

Greetings and thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buried in that stack trace is the real problem: `UaException: timed out waiting for acknowledge`.

Maybe your firewall or network setup is blocking it, or maybe the server didn't send it back, but the problem is that the client never received the `Acknowledge` message in response to its `Hello`.

FWIW, I can run the `ReadExample` against that public server with no issue. In `ReadExample` I overrode `getSecurityPolicy()` and returned `SecurityPolicy.None` and in `ClientExampleRunner` just replaced the endpoint URL.

Comment: Okay so the firewall seemed to be the problem. although i dont understand why, since i can connect to the sample-server with other clients (tested with Integration Objects and Prosys OPC UA Clients)